# Dealing with Null in javascript

Tags: javascript, null

I'm facing some difficulty when dealing with `null` values in JavaScript. I have two cases in my JavaScript where the object can be `null` or can have some other value so I do this:

```
if(feild_values != null || typeof(feild_values) != 'null') {
    alert(feild_values.id[i-1]);
}
```

However, Firebug gives me an error saying:

```
TypeError: feild_values is null alert(feild_values.id[i-1]);
```

How do I manage this?

Comment: @arxanas - Indeed, I hope that is an error that will not propagate through a large project. People need to realize how confusing spelling errors can be, especially in a dynamic language like JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove || typeof(feild_values) != 'null'

You don't need it and typeof(null) isn't 'null', its 'object'

Can simplify to:

```
if (feild_values) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Also, you should use the `!==` operator.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the best replacement. The code path will fail if `feild_values` is non-empty string or even Boolean true.

Comment: That's for sure, but if your data isn't the right type, you've got a bug somewhere else. There's no need to be paranoid and write super defensive code that hides bugs.

Answer (score 0):

you should also be looking for typeof yourVar == "undefined"